# How to avoid NA answers when using as.Date?

Tags: r, date, date-formatting

I have been trying to transform the following column into a `yyyy - mm - dd` data object in R, with the following script, without succeeding.

It creates a `NA` column instead of it; maybe because there are single quotation marks (`"'"`) at the beginning and at the end of each value.

I've tried to look as similar posts, but they didn't solve this problem.

How can I solve this issue?

```
f8$Date
           [1] "'2016-01-05 08:44:10'" "'2016-01-05 08:45:51'" "'2016-01-05 08:45:54'" "'2016-01-05 08:46:24'" "'2016-01-05 08:46:24'"
           [6] "'2016-01-05 08:57:39'" "'2016-01-05 09:01:44'" "'2016-01-05 09:01:45'" "'2016-01-05 09:13:23'" "'2016-01-05 09:15:00'" ...

f8$Date <- as.Date(as.character(f8$Date), format = "%Y-%m-%d")
```

Comment: None of the 3 answers good enough to accept??

Answer (score 2):

Try putting the initial quote into your format, so that `format = "'%Y-%m-%d"`. `as.Date()` will forget the rest of the string since the date is right after the `'`.  From `help(as.Date)`:

> Character strings are processed as far as necessary for the format specified: any trailing characters are ignored.

So we have

```
as.Date("'2016-01-05 08:44:10'", format = "'%Y-%m-%d")
# [1] "2016-01-05"
```

Answer (score 2):

**1) substring** Skip over the leading ' and then use `as.Date`:

```
as.Date(substring(dates, 2))
## [1] "2016-01-05" "2016-01-05" "2016-01-05" "2016-01-05" "2016-01-05"
## [6] "2016-01-05" "2016-01-05" "2016-01-05" "2016-01-05" "2016-01-05"
```

**2) chartr** This would work too and gives the same answer -- it translates each single quote to space and then applies `as.Date`.

```
as.Date(chartr("'", " ", dates))
```

**3) sub** This is almost the same as (2) but uses `sub` instead of `chartr` and only replaces the first ' as that is sufficient. Also it replaces it with the empty string instead of a space -- either would work.

```
as.Date(sub("'", "", dates))
```

**4) scan** Yet another approach is to use `scan` like this:

```
as.Date(scan(text = dates, what = "", quiet = TRUE))
```

**Note:** It is assumed that the input `dates` is:

```
dates <- c("'2016-01-05 08:44:10'", "'2016-01-05 08:45:51'", "'2016-01-05 08:45:54'", 
"'2016-01-05 08:46:24'", "'2016-01-05 08:46:24'", "'2016-01-05 08:57:39'", 
"'2016-01-05 09:01:44'", "'2016-01-05 09:01:45'", "'2016-01-05 09:13:23'", 
"'2016-01-05 09:15:00'")
```

Answer (score 0):

Any In-build function you use must contain the format in which you are giving the input. One way to do the same can be as shown below. I have created a data table but you can work with data frame too. The most important part is `as.POSIXct(strptime(Time,'%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S'))`- If you see we need to specify the format in which input string is specified.

**Note:** Single quote within the double quote hold no significance, so I have removed it.

**Regarding format specification you can refer the below link-**
https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~s133/dates.html

```
library(data.table)
Time=data.table(Time=c("2016-01-05 08:44:10","2016-01-05 08:45:51","2016-01-05 08:45:54","2016-01-05 08:46:24", "2016-01-05 08:46:24","2016-01-05 08:57:39","2016-01-05 09:01:44","2016-01-05 09:01:45","2016-01-05 09:13:23","2016-01-05 09:15:00")) 

Time[,Time_updated:=as.POSIXct(strptime(Time,'%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S'))]
```